# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined - using ref property of imported component in v-if (vue3)

Tags: if-statement, vuejs3, lifecycle, ref, audio-player

I am trying to integrate a audio player into a vue3 site. The component I aim to use is this one [Link](https://github.com/1014156094/vue-audio-player/).

I trying to create a play/pause button that I can place anywhere on my site (separately from the player). I use v-if to switch what the button displays (depending on whether sound is played or not), and use the "isPlaying" property that I get from the player.

What I now struggle with is that when I load the page, caused by line 2 below: "!this.$refs.audioPlayer.isPlaying"

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isPlaying')
```

My understanding so far is that the the ref is not yet available when the component gets rendered, for which it causes an issue. I tried using different approaches (mounted, watchers, setup..) but I keep banging my head against the wall.

Any pointers how to address this correctly would be appreciated.

Funny enough: When I change "!this.$refs.audioPlayer.isPlaying" simply to "true" when loading the page, and then replacing the "true" again with the "!this.$refs.audioPlayer.isPlaying" when the page is already loaded, I can see that the button works correctly..

Many thanks!

```
<template>
  <div v-if="!this.$refs.audioPlayer.isPlaying" class="audio__play-start"  @click.stop="this.$refs.audioPlayer.play"><q-icon name="play_circle"></q-icon></div>
  <div v-else class="audio__play-pause" @click.stop="this.$refs.audioPlayer.pause"><q-icon name="pause_circle"></q-icon></div>
  
  <div>
    <audio-player
      ref="audioPlayer"
      :audio-list="audioList.map(elm => elm.url)"
      theme-color="black"
      :show-prev-button="false"
      :show-next-button="false"
      :show-play-button="false"
      :show-volume-button="false"
      :show-playback-rate="false"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

export default {
  data() {
    return { audioList: [{ name: 'audio1', url: 'rock.mp3'}]}
  },
}
</script>
```

the AudioPlayer I import in my main.ts:

```
import AudioPlayer from '@liripeng/vue-audio-player'
app.use(AudioPlayer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right `$refs.audioPlayer` is not available when the v-if executes so it immediately produces an error.  You could try using `&&` in the v-if to check that `this.$refs.audioPlayer` is truthy before trying to check for the `isPlaying` property.

```html
<div v-if="this.$refs.audioPlayer && !this.$refs.audioPlayer.isPlaying"
```

Comment: Sorry, I removed option B.  I see now that `this.$refs.audioPlayer` when undefined is resulting in `v-if=!undefined` which is "true".  Option A is the only good option.  Why it's always false I'm not sure.  I'm not familiar with the specific library.  Maybe that property isn't reactive and requires the use of `computed` or a watch?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

I had to 1) create include the audioplayer's ref in the setup(), and 2) use a computed attribute (as yoduh had suggested in his comment to my question).

Thanks!

```
<template>
  <div v-if="!isPlaying" class="audio__play-start"  @click.stop="this.$refs.audioPlayer.play"><q-icon name="play_circle"></q-icon></div>
  <div v-else class="audio__play-pause" @click.stop="this.$refs.audioPlayer.pause"><q-icon name="pause_circle"></q-icon></div>
  
  <div>
    <audio-player
      ref="audioPlayer"
      :audio-list="audioList.map(elm => elm.url)"
      theme-color="black"
      :show-prev-button="false"
      :show-next-button="false"
      :show-play-button="false"
      :show-volume-button="false"
      :show-playback-rate="false"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';

export default {
  
  setup () {
    const audioPlayer =  ref(Object)
    const isPlaying = computed(() => {  
      return audioPlayer.value.isPlaying
    })

    return {
      audioList: [{ url: './api/soundfiles?path=/tmp&filename=rock.mp3'}],
      audioPlayer,
      isPlaying
    }
  },

}
</script>
```